# Ringing or flickering effect with images

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am getting Ringing and flickering kind of effect with images having sharp contrast.

[image]

Here i have mapped a image on a sphere and around the edges this effect is very prominent.

These are my texture setting.

```
Texture2D::Texture2D()
    : Width(0), Height(0), Internal_Format(GL_RGB), Image_Format(GL_RGB), Wrap_S(GL_REPEAT), Wrap_T(GL_REPEAT), Filter_Min(GL_LINEAR), Filter_Max(GL_LINEAR) , WrapMode(SumTextureDecl::TextureWrapMode::Repeat)
{
    glGenTextures(1, &this->ID);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Texture2D::Generate(GLuint width, GLuint height, unsigned char* data)
{
    this->Width = width;
    this->Height = height;
    // Create Texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->ID);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, this->Internal_Format, width, height, 0, this->Image_Format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    // Set Texture wrap and filter modes
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, this->Wrap_S);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, this->Wrap_T);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, this->Filter_Min);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, this->Filter_Max);
    // Unbind texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's missing mipmaps/proper filtering settings. Do you have them generated? What texture filtering do you use?

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz i have updated the texture setting.

Comment: Right. So try `glGenerateMipmap` and change the filtering to e.g. `LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`.

Comment: @@Bartek Banachewicz Thanks by generating the mipmap and setting the min filter to LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an issue that is typically solved by using [mipmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap). Linear filtering alone doesn't produce effects that are good enough when the object being rendered forces sampling very few texels which are far apart.

Mipmapping solves that issue by pre-processing the image into lower level-of-detail, which then serves as a source of high-density information for the sampler.

The use of them in OpenGL requires one additional call to `glGenerateMipmaps`, accompanied by one of the four texture minification filtering modes (`GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`) with the word `MIPMAP` in them (e.g. `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`); they provide four possible combinations of linear/nearest texel filtering with linear/nearest mipmap "selection".

To improve the results even more, [anisotropic filtering](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_Object#Anisotropic_filtering) can be used to sharpen the details of mipmapped textures at a slight performance penalty (on newer hardware). It [doesn't replace mipmapping](https://web.archive.org/web/20180713155702/https://www.geforce.com/whats-new/guides/aa-af-guide#1), but improves upon it, taking into account trapeizodal shape of texels of objects being drawn at steep angles relative to the camera.